# Kicked out back to Windows 10 login whilst disconnecting from WiFi

Tags: windows-10, administrator

I am an administrator on a laptop and was doing some work on the user account of the laptop user this evening.

Whilst changing from one Wi-Fi connection to another the screen went black (apart from the taskbar) and then I was kicked back to the windows login screen. Basically what happened was I testing a VPN connection whilst in the Office by tethering the connection to my mobile phone. I disconnected that connection and then asked the computer to forget the details. (in the network settings in the system tray). I was then going to reconnect to the Office WIFI but then the screen went black and then reverted back to the login screen.

I had done it several times that evening with no such issues - which is why it alarmed me as kicking you out to the login screen seems strange.

This was all done under the users account and not my admin account.

What would have caused this and is it anything to worry about?

Presume there is no impact on my admin account as I was not logged onto that?

Unfortunately, I have already given them staff member the laptop. This was something I reflected on afterwards - if there is a major problem I will ask for it back.

Comment: This also could be connected to the VPN Windows 10 issue that was patched this week.  What patches were most recently installed on the machine in question?  What version of Windows 10 are you running?  What was the last cumulative update installed? Please edit your question instead of replying with a comment

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by TightVNC being installed on the computer and someone being connected to it at the time.

TightVNC has an option that allows the computer to be locked, or the user logged out when disconnecting the remote session disconnects.  If this option is enabled, and someone was remotely connected to the computer then disconnecting from the wifi would cause them to disconnect.  That would then trigger this option causing the system to lock or the user to logout.